# I control the world, almost but not, what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I control the world, almost but not

my father has lost something entirely

I was known before I was born

I contain both the living and the unliving

I have a granddaughter who knows everything

not everyone trusts her, but is still well known and loved

The apparatus of conception is what made me grow

And I still continue to grow

Hint #1

> What my father has lost, makes him shine
>  He is not a star but wants to be among them

Hint #2

> I was born in a bubble
>  and my father has sad origin

Hint #3

> I was not a man and not referred to as man-made in ancient times 
>  Today it can be said I am man-made, and man-destroyed, but not in the same place

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Cronos?

I control the world, almost but not

> Cronos ate all of his children except Zeus, god of the gods in the Greek mythology. Also, Cronos is the leader of the first generation of Titans.

my father has lost something entirely

> Cronos emasculated his father Ouranos

I was known before I was born

> <strike>Ouranos originally contained his 12 children in his spouse's entrails</strike> Chronos is often associated with his paronym Chronos, divinity of time. Time existed with space before anything else

I contain both the living and the unliving

> Cronos took his father's leader spot and was also considered as leader of the immortals (hence unliving)? Also, death doesn't escape time so I guess we can consider the living and unliving to belong to time

I have a granddaughter who knows everything

not everyone trusts her, but is still well known and loved

> One of his granddaughters is the goddess of love, Aphrodite. Not everyone trust love yet almost everyone aspires to get it

The apparatus of conception is what made me grow

And I still continue to grow

> Time doesn't exist if we're not conscious of it, and according to the Big Bang theory, time and space continue to expand

Comment: Agreed, but the last part is more like about time continuing, doesn't need to involve any lack-of-imagination-stuff like "big pew thing".

Comment: This is just my scientific rigor speaking here, space and time expansion induced by the Big Bang (which explains why time goes on) is still a theory ;)

Comment: Would be nice to have a philosophical debate about that time part, but it's not the place in this comment section.

Comment: @Overmind we could still go to chat.

Comment: You're on the right track regarding it being mentioned Greek mythology. But it is not a myth.

Answer (score 2):

I control the world/ my father has lost something entirely.

> The passing of time.

I was known before I was born/ I contain both the living and the  unliving.

> Time existed always and the passage of time contains the living and the unliving.

I have a granddaughter who knows everything not everyone trusts but most people love.

> The future... not everyone trusts but most people love.

The apparatus of conception is what made me grow and I still continue to grow.

> After the big bang the arrow of time continuously grows.

Answer (score 1):

Still a work in progress
But so far my current Answer

> Tefnut

my father has lost something entirely

> As indicated by wikipedia[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Ra#Procreative], After " Shu and Tefnut, the children of this creator god, have drifted away from him in the waters of Nu" Atum/Ra "sends out his Eye to find them. The Eye returns with Shu and Tefnut but is infuriated to see that the creator has developed a new eye, which has taken her place". Thus in losing his original eye (although he generates a new one), he loses the "Eye of Ra". As an alternative explanation, seeing as the previous was weak, instead another variant can be considered, wherein "the Eye goddess becomes upset with Ra and runs away from him." thus in this instance, Ra permanently loses the original eye, and does not claim her by "by giving her an exalted position on his forehead in the form of the uraeus".

I have a granddaughter who knows everything

> According to wikipedia[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isis#Mother_goddess], Isis, Tefnut's grandaughter, "By virtue of her magical knowledge ...  was said to be "more clever than a million gods".

The apparatus of conception is what made me grow

> According to Wikipedia[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefnut#Mythology] Tefnut "is said to produce pure waters from her vagina.". Vaginae being genitalia, the "appartus of conception", and her's able to produce "pure waters" coupled with herself a deity "of moisture, moist air, dew and rain" would, by my inferring from this data, be self-nourished and thus grow.(This isn't based on research but itself is my own inferrance).

What my father has lost, makes him shine

> What the Father, Ra, lost, the Eye of Ra, makes him shine. Again consulting wikipedia yields a description of the solar uraeus: " [it] represents the Eye as a dangerous force that encircles the sun god and guards against his enemies, spitting flames like venom.". Note "spitting flams like venom", which as flames produce light, causes "him [to] shine".

i was born in a bubble

> According to (wikipedia)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefnut#Mythological_origins], Tefnut arose either from the act of sneezing: "Atum was creative in that he proceeded to sneeze while in Heliopolis. And brother and sister were born - that is Shu and Tefnut" OR being spat out: "In some versions of this myth, Atum also spits out his saliva, which forms the act of procreation. ", which both involve liquids, able to contain of pockets of air, and thus satisfy her being born in a bubble.

and my father has sad origin

> Her father Atum-Ra, is said to have "created his children—the first deities, out of loneliness." according to wikipedia[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atum#Relationship_to_other_gods]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a

> Satellite

I control the world, almost but not
my father has lost something entirely

> Satellite communications are widely used in control operations
>  Father = launch vehicle, it jettisons boosters and stages

I was known before I was born
I contain both the living and the unliving

> Natural satellites (the moon) existed long before artificial ones
>  There are both manned and unmanned artificial satellites

I have a granddaughter who knows everything
not everyone trusts her, but is still well known and loved

> Not sure about his clue

The apparatus of conception is what made me grow
And I still continue to grow

> Several satellite constellations are still being expanded

What my father has lost, makes him shine
He is not a star but wants to be among them

> Launch vehicles head towards the stars, but lose their flame and boosters along the way

I was born in a bubble
and my father has sad origin

> Satellites are typically assembled in a cleanroom (bubble).
>  Launch vehicles were derived from intercontinental ballistic missiles, sad origin indeed

I was not a man and not referred to as man-made in ancient times
Today it can be said I am man-made, and man-destroyed, but not in the same place

> The moon is a natural satellite, known from ancient times
>  Satellites are made on the ground but destroyed in space/upper atmosphere